# Conversion to xts does not work because data is of type 'character' and cannot be converted to 'numeric'

Tags: r, character, numeric, xts, data-conversion

I have the following data set

```
data
     date PX_LAST.USGG10YR Index PX_LAST.GSWISS10 Index
1  2012-12-31                 1.7574                  0.526
2  2013-01-31                 1.9849                  0.789
3  2013-02-28                 1.8756                  0.698
4  2013-03-29                 1.8486                  0.716
5  2013-04-30                 1.6717                  0.570
6  2013-05-31                 2.1282                  0.722
7  2013-06-28                 2.4857                  1.027
8  2013-07-31                 2.5762                  1.023
9  2013-08-30                 2.7839                  1.069
10 2013-09-30                 2.6100                  1.021
```

The class of the date column is

```
> class(data[,1])
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

The class of the other two columns is

> class(data[,2])
>       [1] "numeric"
>   class(data[,3])
>       [1] "numeric"

I am now converting this to its with

```
df2=xts(data,order.by=data$date)
```

The result is

```
structure(c("2012-12-31", "2013-01-31", "2013-02-28", "2013-03-29", 
"2013-04-30", "2013-05-31", "2013-06-28", "2013-07-31", "2013-08-30", 
"2013-09-30", "1.7574", "1.9849", "1.8756", "1.8486", "1.6717", 
"2.1282", "2.4857", "2.5762", "2.7839", "2.61", "0.526", "0.789", 
"0.698", "0.716", "0.57", "0.722", "1.027", "1.023", "1.069", 
"1.021"), .Dim = c(10L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("date", 
"PX_LAST.USGG10YR Index", "PX_LAST.GSWISS10 Index")), index = structure(c(1356912000, 
1359590400, 1362009600, 1364515200, 1367280000, 1369958400, 1372377600, 
1375228800, 1377820800, 1380499200), tzone = "UTC", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "UTC", tzone = "UTC", class = c("xts", 
"zoo"))
```

Looking at the result, I get

```
> typeof(df2)
[1] "character"
```

Clearly, I cannot use this for calculations (such as Return.calculate). When I try to convert columns 2 and 3 with as.numeric(df2[,2]), it remains as type 'character'. Can somebody help me to find a code which does convert this to a proper xts (i.e. columns 2 and 3 are of type 'double'), i.e. the structure of df2 is like in this example

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols('AAA',src='FRED')
class(AAA)
typeof(AAA)
> class(AAA)
[1] "xts" "zoo"
> typeof(AAA)
[1] "double
```

Regards
Andreas

Answer (score 4):

You included the `date` column in the xts data, so R converted your data.frame into a matrix using the type that wouldn't lose any information (character).  There's no need to have the `date` column as the xts index *and* in the data, so just omit that column when you call `xts()`.

```
df2 <- xts(data[,-1], order.by=data$date)
```

Comment: Dear Joshua, many many thanks for your solution. It works perfectly and I am a happy camper. Best regards, Andreas